# several regex queries

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I need some help writing regex.

this is my first regex expression(match either English or Hebrew chars):

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i
```

this should be match: abc, אבג
this should not be match:a , b, aא

It works ok, I just need to also add limitaion for more then 1 char.

The next one should be exactly like the one above(including the more than 1 char
limitation) but to also allow spaces.
this should be match: abcx, abcx ascx, דגהק , שגד דשגב
this should not be match:a , b, asaceדגעההת, ascasv  אקיכרעקכ

The last Regex expression should be all digits, contain exactly 10 digits 
and to start with the numbers 05.
this should be match: 0528547114
this should not be match: digits, special chars,  less or more than
10 digits.
I'm using JS and C# Regex.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please include examples of what should and should not be matched. Also which variant of regexes are you using?

Comment: Read [ask]. Create a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match more than 1 character use the quantifier `{2,}` instead of `+`:

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]{2,}|[\w]{2,})$/i
```

To match space, add it in the character class:

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40 ]{2,}|[\w ]{2,})$/i
```

To match 10 digits:

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40 ]{2,}|[\w ]{2,}|05\d{8})$/i
```

To match several words separated by one space:

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]{2,}(?: [\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]{2,})*|\w{2,}(?: \w{2,})*|05\d{8})$/i
```

Comment: thank you, the first two were just what I needed, 
but the last one wasn't - I need it to have only numbers(0-9) , to have 
exactly 10 numbers and the first 2 numbers to be 05. 
something like: 053256899. 
I think I got it: ^05+\d{8}$

Comment: @Jonny: just change `\d{10}` into `05\d{8}`, see my edit.